# Attach IntelliJ IDEA debugger to a remote java -server running process

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I run Java appliaction on Ubuntu virtual machine with command:

```
java -showversion -server -Xmx512M -Drps.home=${RPS_HOME} \
-Dcontainer.host=${CONTAINER_HOST} \
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=$4 \
-classpath ${RPS_LIBS} com.softel.rps.impl.core.SPEngine ${CONFIG} \
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9999
```

I opened port 9999 with command (an also forwarded port in VirtualBox):

```
sudo ufw allow 9999/tcp
```

And I try to attach debugger with IntelliJ IDEA:
[image: IDEA debug]

And finally i end up with error

```
IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed"
```

Im not very well experienced in remote debugging. Can you tell me is it possible to attach debugger to java -server process?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42392922/104891. Verify with `telnet` that you can connect to the specified host/port, the issue may be with the configuration or your network settings. For instance, `localhost` on your screenshot looks suspicious since you are connecting to a different machine (VM). Unless you have port forwarding enabled from `localhost` to the VM, it will not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to specify -agentlib options before everything else:

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9999
-showversion -server -Xmx512M -Drps.home=${RPS_HOME} \
-Dcontainer.host=${CONTAINER_HOST} \
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=$4 \
-classpath ${RPS_LIBS} com.softel.rps.impl.core.SPEngine ${CONFIG}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start your application with the command below:

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -jar .\your_app.jar -showversion -server
```

and start a remote debugger from your idea (mine is the idea):

Edit Configuration > (+) add Remote JVM Debug with default option :)

[image]