# Can IntelliJ IDEA or Eclipse run UI on one OS, but compile-build-execute in a container on another OS?

Tags: java, eclipse, docker, intellij-idea, containers

We have a tomcat webapp with a number of build and runtime dependencies that take time and effort to install. So we isolated build and runtime environment to docker containers and it works fine.. except for that you interact with a build container by running a script possibly with a couple of parameters and that's it.

This way we get always get a clean and working environment, a working build, but loose the modern IDE advantages such as compiling only what's really needed, hot-replacing classes in the tomcat app, etc. We are applying workarounds that are basically reinvent these IDE features in the script, but.. there got to be another way hopefully.

**Is there a way to run Eclipse or IntelliJ idea on one OS (Mac OS X in my case) and run-build-compile inside a container or a virtual machine?**

You know, sort of X-Window style: IDE on my main OS to be just the UI with the familiar host system keyboard shortcuts and look, but all the IDEs "engine" to be executed in a separate container/VM.

P.S.
Or am I asking the wrong question? What's your solution for IDE-enabled development if you do want to setup-maintain build-runtime environments in one place only?

Comment: I don't know about Eclipse, but certainly JetBrains tools have Docker support; see e.g. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/docker.html

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/42392922/104891.

Answer (score 0):

In **Eclipse**, you can use ***[Eclipse Docker Tooling](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-docker-tooling)*** to manage and run Docker containers. With the ***[Execute Shell](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Linux_Tools_Project/Docker_Tooling/User_Guide)*** command a shell in a running container can be opened to run a build.

If a CI server is running in the container, you can use [Eclipse Mylyn Builds](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/Builds) (with e. g. [the Jenkins/Hudson connector](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/hudsonjenkins-mylyn-builds-connector)) to run a build (and get stack traces of a failed build).