# How to run Java project to the server in intelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to deploy my Java project in IntelliJ IDEA CE to the server as an API, can somebody please remind me how to do this?

I'm sure I remember it being just a right click and 'run' somewhere but not sure.

Can you give me step by step please?

Comment: What is stoping you from right clicking on the project and clicking run?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/42392922/104891 help?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run application servers in IntelliJ CE. You can only do this in the Ultimate Edition.

To do this: 
Go to IntelliJ Settings/Preferences -> Go to `Application Servers` under `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> Click the plus sign to add server to your IntelliJ environment. Note: Make sure to point to the location of the license server locally on your machine.

Once you have created a server there, you will be able to run your Java application through IntelliJ. I imagine your issue is using IntelliJ CE. Since you are using CE, you have to run your application server through command line as Community Edition doesn't allow you to do this level of functionality.