# Run from IntelliJ IDEA in remote server using SSH

Tags: intellij-idea, ssh, deployment, ide

Is there a way to run a program in a ssh server from inside IntelliJ IDEA?

I already have a SSH server configured. I can deploy code to it, upload and download.

But I don't want to run it manually inside de server every time I need to test a code change. I just want to run it normally using the UI in IntelliJ IDEA, but when I press the "green button" it actually runs it in the server.

Is this possible?

I have professional version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1 [will have Run Targets feature](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2021/01/intellij-idea-2021-1-eap-1/) for that. You can already [try the EAP version](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/).

For the older versions [check my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42392922/104891).

It's also possible to [run apps in the Docker container](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-a-java-app-in-a-container.html).

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks.