# Main manifest attribute error IntelliJ While running the jar file

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar

I am trying to run my Spark Job using IntelliJ and it ran successfully while working without jar.
Now I am trying to build a jar to run it in some other environment.
After creating the `Jar` I try to run it and had encountered an error:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar /home/aims/workspace/second/target/second-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar local[*] thrift://localhost:9083
no main manifest attribute, in /home/aims/workspace/second/target/second-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried to change the `META-INF` to `resources` folder. Please check it as I have already gone through many suggestions on Stackoverflow related to this particular problem and not a single suggestion helped me. Hence, I am writing this question here. Following it the current location of `META-INF`

```
/home/aims/workspace/second/src/main/resources/META-INF
```

Kindly, let me know how I can run my job successfully using the jar?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891) for the sample working project with a jar, a dependency and a `MANIFEST.MF`.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thank you but didn't worked for me. I tried and same error.

Comment: Share a project to reproduce, the sample project from the link definitely works.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Sure. You have Apache Spark?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Here is my project .. please check it: https://jumpshare.com/v/KtFyyh3gxlEUjVDmafPq

Comment: Sorry, but it's not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). `pom.xml` doesn't specify any dependencies, it doesn't build. I also doubt that it will work when all the spark jars are extracted into the single file since it may override manifests or other important classes and metadata. Try using the jar with linked dependencies vs extracted.

Comment: @CrazyCoder let try...