# Exporting Java project .jar

Tags: java, maven

I have java project. When I export it to **file.jar**, it can't be opened with double click.

When I test with the command line:

```
java -jar file.jar
```

It shows the message:

> No main manifest attribute

but with:

```
java -cp app.jar com.somepackage.SomeClass
```

it runs perfectly.

I use IntelliJ IDEA and maven.
Manifest code:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: StructureClasses.Main
```

Comment: Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891 for the sample project.

Answer (score 1):

if you are importing any pictures or using any other files that are not file.jar create a folder and put all of the other files in use in file.jar in that folder with file.jar.

Comment: It is the same problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using Maven, take a look at the maven-assembly-plugin. I think it already does what you want with is mainClass property.

This is an example from the [official page](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html)

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
      [...]
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <mainClass>org.sample.App</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
    [...]
  </plugin>
```

With this configuration, you should now be able to run the jar file either with double-click or `java -jar`. Remember that the mainClass property must be the fully qualified name of the class.