# Create Executable Jar file in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, executable-jar

would like to make the executable jar file of my project in intellij. I have created jar but while executing jar file, getting this error

> cannot find the path specified of the file config.properties.

Properties file present in the folder ReconFiles and main class present in the folder SRC.

Can you please help me how to add the properties class in the JAR file?

Comment: Configure the path with the properties files as the resource root so that they are copied to the output. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891.

Answer (score 0):

> cannot find the path specified of the file config.properties

Normally jar file will be placed inside target folder. Make sure you are execute in target folder.

Perform `cd target` if you are using `Ubuntu`.

Comment: Hi John. I am using windows7.