# How to run a Java .jar file in IntelliJ? Error - Parameters: archive-name [archive-type]

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar

### Goal & Problem

I have created a Java program in **IntelliJ**. I built it as a .jar file following the instructions [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/creating-running-and-packaging-your-first-java-application.html). When I try to run it, it gives me the following output:

> <s>Parameters: archive-name [archive-type]</s>
>
> no main manifest attribute

**Note:** I have tried to run it in two ways. The first way is through the IDE, and the second way is through command line using the following command: `java -jar jarname.jar`. Both ways have the same result.

---

### What I have tried

[Here is my project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-We-IEiYodqTEJOTlh3Y0VKb2s/view?usp=sharing).

To determine the point of error, I started over with a simple Hello World program, here is my code:

```
public class Producer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

and here is my Maven:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>confluent</id>
        <url>http://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.2.1-cp1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.rxtx</groupId>
        <artifactId>rxtx</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

---

**Note:** I was unable to build it without the repositories and dependencies above in my Maven, so this may have something to do with the problem, but I can't imagine how or why.

Any advice would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the command you are using to run it? It should be `java -jar jarname.jar`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891.

Comment: Yes, I am using that command to run it.

Comment: Share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CrazyCoder Is that not what I have? What additional information do you want?

Comment: Sample project with the jar configuration you've built (artifact).

Comment: @CrazyCoder I'm not sure how to give you that. I am unable to upload anything to stackoverflow.

Comment: Are you aware of the file sharing services like Dropbox, Google Drive, OneDrive, etc?

Comment: @CrazyCoder [Here is the link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-We-IEiYodqTEJOTlh3Y0VKb2s). For some reason the error is now: `no main manifest attribute`

Comment: Main class was in the test root instead of the source root, manifest was in the source root instead of the resources root. Here is the [fixed project](https://mega.nz/#!kgBnyBqB!TcNCtGXpBG1aw_9ZJ_XvXMTjmysuf04LbUhaMHDywik).

Comment: @CrazyCoder I don't see where you made these changes. Could you give me a more detailed answer please?

Comment: Please [check this video](http://i.imgur.com/UZVLvPn.gifv).

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Do you have any other questions?

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly now.

Comment: You are welcome, feel free to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by the files residing in the wrong locations (resources in source roots, sources in test source roots), [this animation](https://i.imgur.com/UZVLvPn.gifv) explains how to fix it.