# Intellij extract maven dependency to artifact

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am currently having an issue with IntelliJ.

I have several dependencies in my pom. However, when I generate an artifact, I can add the maven libraries but instead of maven extracting the jar contents, Maven instead pops the entire jar into the artifact jar. This results in my program failing to load. How can I get IntelliJ to not do this and instead extract the jar contents into the build?

I configured the artifact manually through intelliJ

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is that a web application? How is the packaging configured in pom.xml? Was the artifact generated automatically or you have configured it manually?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven

Comment: @CrazyCoder I made the edits you requested

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891.