# Failed to generate JAR file using Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar

I have created a jar in path `xxx/IdeaProjects/xxx/out/artifacts/abc_jar`.

When I run it using java -jar, I get

```
Could not find or load main class ...
```

I have moved the mainfest file to `xxx/IdeaProjects/xxx/src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

and main class is `com.rh.xxx.Application`, but still getting

```
 Could not find or load main class...
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891 for the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the Start-Class attribute value in MANIFEST.MF file with the fully qualified java class. Verify the same in the generated jar file after the jar is created.

Please refer below, here starter class is the one has main method.

Content of, META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

```
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Start-Class: com.mycompany.project.MyApplication
```

Refer https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html#executable-jar-launcher-manifest for more info.

Comment: shouldn't the .MF is created by intellij itself ?