# IntelliJ JAR File Exporting

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

Does anybody know how to correctly export a jar file from the IntelliJ Environment? I am able to get the jar file, but a message saying...

> Error: A JNI error has occured, please check your installation and try again.

Following another message saying...

> A Java Exception has occured.

Can anybody tell me why this is happening?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891. If you can't make it work, share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I was now able to get the file correctly. But now I'm having an issue with the main. It says it cannot read it. Should I place the .jar file somewhere else for it to be read? Or did I screw up something while I made it?

Comment: We can't tell until you provide a sample as already asked. The linked answer contains the sample project link which you can download and compare to your project that doesn't work.