# Resource folder not included when building jar in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, resources

When I run it in Intellij it works fine but when I try to build it into a jar the resource folder is not added to the jar.

I wrote some code to test if I was getting the path wrong...

```
        String file = File.separator + "resources" + File.separator + "components" + File.separator + "game_window.png";
        while (!file.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(file + ": " + ScreenShot.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file));
            file = file.substring(1);
        }

        gameWindow = ImageIO.read(ScreenShot.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("components" + File.separator + "game_window.png"));
```

which produces the following output in Intellij:

> \resources\components\game_window.png: null
>
> resources\components\game_window.png: null
>
> esources\components\game_window.png: null
>
> sources\components\game_window.png: null
>
> ources\components\game_window.png: null
>
> urces\components\game_window.png: null
>
> rces\components\game_window.png: null
>
> ces\components\game_window.png: null
>
> es\components\game_window.png: null
>
> s\components\game_window.png: null
>
> \components\game_window.png: java.io.BufferedInputStream@723279cf
>
> components\game_window.png: java.io.BufferedInputStream@10f87f48
>
> ect...

while if I run the same code in the jar it produces the following:

> \resources\components\game_window.png: null
>
> resources\components\game_window.png: null
>
> esources\components\game_window.png: null
>
> sources\components\game_window.png: null
>
> ources\components\game_window.png: null
>
> urces\components\game_window.png: null
>
> rces\components\game_window.png: null
>
> ces\components\game_window.png: null
>
> es\components\game_window.png: null
>
> s\components\game_window.png: null
>
> \components\game_window.png: null
>
> components\game_window.png: null
>
> ect...

I am fairly certain the issue is that the resource folder is not being added to the jar.

I am not sure what to do as I have already marked the folder as a resource root...
[image: folder]

Also here's how I'm building my jar

[image: artifact]

Comment: Make sure that the /resources contents are added to the JAR.  Are you using the Maven Shade plug-in to create your fat JAR with all the dependencies inside?  You should be.  Open the JAR and see if that file is inside.  If it's not, you have a packaging problem.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891. Unpack the jar and see what's inside.

Comment: I have unpacked the jar, there is no resource folder

Comment: @java file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA and attach a sample project to reproduce.