# IntelliJ JAR artifacts don't contain module code, only dependency

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, build

I've gone through the regular build artifact process, and can get it to build a JAR. However, the JAR that gets compiled doesn't contain my module code, only the code of the dependencies.

The Output Layout, under Project Structure, lists all the relevant modules
i.e.

```
'abi' compile output
'codegen' compile output
```

etc...

But none of that module code ends up in the JAR.

Possibly related: I'm not indicating a 'main class' because I'm making a JAR library, which does not have a main class.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891 for the sample project. Share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in case the issue persists.

Comment: Tried the above build and it was fine; my build still doesn't contain the module's code, only the dependencies' code, and I don't know why. There are auto-built JARs in the /build/libs folder, and those are fine; I need a JAR that contains all the module classes.