# "A JNI error has occurred" exception when running .jar file

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar, dependencies

I'm running a java application by this command :

*java -cp < FileName> < package name>*

however, it shows

`A JNI error has occurred... 
Exception ... NoClassDefFoundError: ...`

this result is right below
[image]

I've surveyed the post 
[Adding external library to artifact jar in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42196697/adding-external-library-to-artifact-jar-in-intellij-idea)
but still not sure how to solve it.

Here is my Project Structure page, but have no clue to extract the dependencies into the artifact.
[image]

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Done.

I've created a .jar before, and I kept that setting.
After delete & re-add a new .jar file with "extract to the target JAR" option chosen, the .jar file produced could work. Thanks!

[image]