# IntelliJ & Jersey: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jersey, noclassdeffounderror

I just tried to use the jersey-server api in a java application.
It's a maven project and I already added the mysql-connector api which works fine.
When the application which is compressed into a jar (Intellij-Artifacts) runs, it throws the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
com/sun/jersey/api/container/httpserver/HttpServerFactory
at de.myleak.server.Server.init(Server.java:19)
at de.myleak.core.Core.init(Core.java:87)
at de.myleak.core.Core.<init>(Core.java:51)
at de.myleak.core.Core.main(Core.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 4 more
```

I added the dependency to the pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

I also added the maven dependency in the project structure
screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Check the artifact configuration, make sure it includes this dependency.

Comment: How is your jar seeing the other jars? Are they packaged inside it? Then unzip your jar file and check if your jersey server jar is there.

Comment: @CrazyCoder this is the configuration: [link] (https://imgur.com/a/ru5iDPU)

Comment: @AlexisDufrenoy If I unpack the JAR it includes the mysql-connector, jersey-core, jersey-server and jsr33.api JAR

Comment: @str4in jar inside jar will not work, you have to extract it, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891.