# IntelliJ adds a 'generated' folder/package to artifact

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I build a .jar artifact using IntelliJ, it adds an empty folder/package named 'generated' to my jar file. Why is that?

My artifact 'Output Layout':

```
name.jar
-  file.yml
- '%module name%' compile output
```

[image]

Comment: How is your project artifact configured? Sample project from https://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891 doesn't do it, so it must be specific to your project and the only way to tell why it happens is by checking the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Actually, I just realized that every module has a "generated" folder inside out/production/<module name>/ and I'm adding the 'compile output' to the artifact, which includes the "generated" folder. I just created a new module, with stock IntelliJ settings and with a simple hello world class to test it, and it also creates this folder.

Comment: Do you use Maven or Gradle based project?

Comment: For this specific test, neither. It's a "simple" java module. File > New > Module > Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`generated` directory appears in the output if you have [annotation processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ewSw.png) enabled in IntelliJ IDEA compiler settings.

You can disable this option, delete the `generated` directory and rebuild the project and the artifact to make it go away, but it should not affect your application in any way, so you can just ignore it.

Comment: Thanks. I know it doesn't affect anything, is just something I have noticed (I'm moving from Eclipse) and started to wonder what it was about.