# Log4j outputs on console when it should not do it

Tags: java, intellij-idea, log4j

I am writing a Java application in IntelliJ and I am using log4j. I disabled the console output from the xml file, but it keeps outputting when I run the jar (not the java, the JAR). I use this repository for some experiments: https://github.com/optimaize/language-detector

I have already tried to add log4j.properties and different configurations of log4j.xml, but it keeps outputting the console information. This one is my log4j.xml file located at: src/main/resources/log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="false" xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
  <param name="append" value="false" />
  <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" />
  <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10" />
  <param name="file" value="C:/logs/myStruts1App.log" />
</appender>

<root>

 <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
</root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

According to other guides here on stack overflow, this should make it. But when I run the jar: `java -jar MyJar.jar` it outputs

```
17:20:41.017 [main] DEBUG c.o.langdetect.LanguageDetectorImpl - ==> [DetectedLanguage[bn:0.9999940935958097]]
17:20:41.019 [main] DEBUG c.o.langdetect.LanguageDetectorImpl - ==> [DetectedLanguage[bn:0.9999940935958097]]
17:20:41.020 [main] DEBUG c.o.langdetect.LanguageDetectorImpl - ==> [DetectedLanguage[en:0.9999940935958097]]
17:20:41.020 [main] DEBUG c.o.langdetect.LanguageDetectorImpl - ==> [DetectedLanguage[fr:0.9999940935958097]] ...
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891) has the [working example](ftp://ftp.intellij.net/pub/.idea/HelloWithDependencies.zip).

If you remove `stdout,` from `log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file` line in `HelloWithDependencies\resources\log4j.properties` file and rebuild the `.jar` artifact, it will not produce any console output, the logging will go into the file only.

Comment: This is my log4j.properties and it still console outputs:                                                            # Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = info, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n

Comment: @Mazzespazze please download the example and see how the project is configured.