# How to fix the NoClassDefFoundError in IntelliJ Idea after having tried every way to add stdlib.jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dependencies, libraries, noclassdeffounderror

I've created a simple Java project in IntelliJ Idea 2018 and I'm trying to add `stdlib` to my project.

After spending hours investigating online I tried doing so the following ways:

1. Create a `libs` folder inside the `src` folder, copy and paste the `stdlib.jar` and right-click it and select `Add as a Library`;
2. Go to `Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies -> + JARs or directories` and selecting the stdlib.jar

I found people complaining about doing this but IntelliJ was not suggesting the import needed to use `StdOut`, for example. However, when I add the `stdlib.jar` file and package it, IntelliJ instantly suggests the import I should use, and there are no errors whatsoever.

Still, when I try to run the project it invariantly runs into the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

I've spent hours investigating this, trying different ways to add the library and import it, but the outcome is always the same.

I've attached a print screen that shows my current project structure, import, and use of the `stdlib.jar`.

Really hope you guys can help me.
Thanks!

**Link to download `stdlib-package.jar`** - https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/stdlib-package.jar

**MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Main-Class: com.edgelab.hospital.Application
```

**HOSPITAL_SIMULATOR_JAR.xml**

```
<component name="ArtifactManager">
  <artifact type="jar" name="hospital-simulator:jar">
    <output-path>$PROJECT_DIR$</output-path>
    <root id="archive" name="hospital-simulator.jar">
      <element id="module-output" name="HospitalSimulator" />
    </root>
  </artifact>
</component>
```

**stdlib-package.xml**

```
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="stdlib-package">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/../stdlib-package.jar!/" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES>
      <root url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/../stdlib-package.jar!/" />
    </SOURCES>
  </library>
</component>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please add your run configuration for that jar? It looks like the `stdlib.jar` is not added to the classpath. Therefore, it cannot be found.

Comment: Please, don't do screenshots. Post your code and error message. Also, it would be helpful if you post a link to download this lib.

Comment: First of all you are using stdlib-package.jar, not stdlib.jar(seems like this one contains source code in default package). Second, just do right click on your project -> Open Module Settings -> Libraries -> "+" -> Java -> specify your stdlib-package.jar -> Apply OK. I just checked, it works for me this way.

Comment: @SergeiSirik that's what I first tried and it doesn't work.
What I've found is that when I try to run the stdlib-package.jar it says that there is no main manifest attribute, but I can't edit it. 
My hospital-simulator.jar has the main class attribute.

Comment: @Peter  I believe I've added everything you asked for.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run a jar created from your project. This will only work if you either include the classes from the library in your project jar (i.e., create a 'fat jar'), or include stdlib.jar in your runtime classpath (i.e., run your project with `java -cp /path/to/stdlib.jar:/path/to/hospital-simulator.jar com.edgelab.hospital.Application`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally solved it. Here's what was wrong: Nothing.

After searching the web I found (for some reason I can't post the link) an answer which suggested copying my code, deleting the project and creating a new one.
So, I deleted my project, created a new one with the same code, created the same artifacts, added the `stdlib-package.jar` as a library and rebuilt the `hospital-simulator.jar` and it worked instantly.

I can't explain why this works, as I have no idea. I literally did the same thing by the same order. Hope this helps someone and thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Comment: You were trying to run the JAR artifact which didn't include the dependency, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html and https://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891 for the example.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I rebuilt the artifact several times, and I believe that can't be the reason due to the following: To verify that that wasn't the case, when I created the new project I built the JAR artifact and only after added the stdlib-package.jar. I then rebuild the JAR artifact and it worked.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA doesn't update artifact automatically when you add a new library to the project. You need to change the artifact configuration manually before rebuilding it.

Comment: Yes, I know and I did. Believe me. I sincerely have no idea what happened. Might not even be IntelliJ related at this point. I honestly don't know.