# How do I export SQLJDBC into JAR correctly in Intellij?

Tags: java, sql-server, intellij-idea, jar, minecraft

I'm setting up a SQL connector for my bukkit plugin, but whenever I compile into a jar file and try running from the server I get

> java.sql.SQLEXCEPTION: No suitable driver found.

I have tried adding in the line

```java
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

Whenever I put that I get

> SQLEXCEPTION: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

This problem only occurs when I put it into a jar file and not when I test it in my IDE.

I currently use Intellij.

This is my current Jar setup:
https://gyazo.com/94341b7bb47121a0416deaee6279dd30

```java
 public ConnectionUtils(String url, String us, String pa) throws SQLException
    {
        SQLServerDriver dr = new SQLServerDriver();
        user = us;
        pass = pa;
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, us, pa);
        isConnected = true;
        this.url = url;
    }
```

Comment: How are you compiling it? What build tool are you using? Try running your app with `java -classpath <path-to-jars> MyApp.jar com.foo.MyMainClass`

Comment: This is a minecraft plugin for a bukkit server so I am not running any particular arguments.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution using Project Structure

Outside of using maven, you can look at your Project Structure in IntelliJ and examine your dependencies. Make sure the "export" box next that jar is checked.

---

### Maven Solution

I recommend using maven to handle your dependencies, as you can define the scope of the dependency, as explained [here](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-dependency-scopes).

For the JDBC dependency, you could use the following dependency declaration in your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.17</version>
</dependency>
```

This would inherit the default scope which, as stated in the article, is compile.

> 3.1. Compile
>
> This is the default scope when no other scope is provided.
>
> Dependencies with this scope are available on the classpath of the
>   project in all build tasks and they're propagated to the dependent
>   projects.

---

### Manifest

It seems some people online are talking about exactly this issue, and the solution is one that @Bohemian mentioned for ensuring that the required class is packaged with the jar. However, that solution only works if you are executing the jar from the command line, which is not the case with spigot plugins. I suggest creating a MANIFEST.txt and including the driver class-path in there, as suggested by Terence Gronowski on CodeRanch

> Creating a Manifest.txt file with the following contents in the
>   program folder:
>
> Manifest-Version: 1.0 Class-Path: sqljdbc4.jar Main-Class:
>   ParkplatzVerwaltung (Newline)
>
> Don't forget to end with a newline. The important thing is
>   "Class-Path: sqljdbc4.jar", showing where the driver is.

Source: https://coderanch.com/t/529484/databases/Jdbc-driver-putting-application-jar

Comment: Added in my pom.xml:
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.1.jre11</version>
        </dependency>

Also attempted using the checkbox on the dependencies and still the same results

Comment: Take a look at editing the jars manifest file to include your required Class. https://coderanch.com/t/529484/databases/Jdbc-driver-putting-application-jar