# Unable to make an executable jar with external dependency of Intellij form project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a Java project which useses Intellij form to display a window application with external dependency but I tired following method to create executable JAR then it is getting executed (not even error message)

File>Project structure>artifacts> + >JAR woth dependency >OK
Build > Build artifacts > JAR will be created then double click ---> no output

My file structure:

```
Project abc
----+src
-------+main
------------+java
-----------------class1.java
-----------------+pack
---------------------->class2.java
---------------------->feature.form
-------------+resources
----------------->jar1.jar
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891. If it doesn't help, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder but it didnt help

Comment: In this case you need to provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get further assistance.

Comment: Your question lacks the details to get the good answer. When asked for details, you've ignored the request. Now you blame us for not helping. It makes no sense.

Answer (score -1):

I have found a way if you are creating a window using Intellij 'form' then better make your class extend Application (javafx class) and call the form in the launch method.

then follow  search in google create javafx jar with intellij