# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when loading class with URLClassLoader

Tags: java, classloader, classnotfoundexception

I have a JAR file that looks like this:

```
MacBook@ ~/workspace-sync/mparnisa_dynamodb2/out/artifacts/dynamodb $ jar tf dynamodb.jar | head
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
mparnisa-dynamodb-table.json
com/
com/mparnisa/
com/mparnisa/dynamodb/
com/mparnisa/dynamodb/table/
com/mparnisa/dynamodb/table/ResourceModel$ResourceModelBuilder.class
com/mparnisa/dynamodb/table/ResourceModel.class
com/amazonaws/AmazonServiceException.class
// and many more...
```

From an IntelliJ project, I want to create an instance of `ResourceModel`, which looks like this:

```
package com.mparnisa.dynamodb.table;

@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
public class ResourceModel {
```

So in my code I wrote this:

```java
File file  = new File("/Users/mparnisa/workspace-sync/mparnisa_dynamodb2/out/artifacts/dynamodb/dynamodb.jar");

URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};

ClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls);

String resourceModelClassName = "com.mparnisa.dynamodb.table.ResourceModel";

Class<?> resourceModelClass = urlClassLoader.loadClass(resourceModelClassName);
```

but the last line throws an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mparnisa.dynamodb.table.ResourceModel
```

Comment: @Michael no, i'm not a beginner. I can't do `import com.mparnisa.dynamodb.table.CreateHandler` because of reasons that are not relevant to this question

Comment: @Michael because I won't know until runtime what class I need to instantiate

Comment: From what I can tell, your jar contains other jars. The class you want to import is within one of the nested jars. The usual way to create a fat jar involves effectively unzipping all of the dependency jars (Maven shade plugin will do this). That is, you would end up with directories containing .class files, but no jars. Spring Boot allows nested jars but it has it's own classloader which knows how to find classes in these nested jars. The default classloader won't do that.

Comment: @Michael the class I want to load is within the JAR (it's not nested). But I think your point still applies... So I need to create a fat jar? Is there no other solution?

Comment: The class you want to load is in the jar but it's failing before that. It fails on `AmazonServiceException`, which from the output you listed, is not at the top-level of the jar. Fat jar is the easy solution, yes. In fact what you have is already kind of a fat jar (the dependencies are bundled with your code) but it is not structured in a way that's usable by the default classloader.

Comment: `AmazonServiceException` is within `aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.728.jar`. Is there a way I can structure this JAR better? I generated it using IntelliJ artifacts, as in [option 2 of this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/1623249).

Comment: I don't know how option 2 is ever supposed to work. AFAIK the classloader will not check the manifest. And well, you can see yourself that it doesn't load the class. I am not familiar with IntelliJ artifact configuration, but it looks like you want to right click the dependency and do "Extract in output root" - the first option they mention. Not 'put'.

Comment: Yes, I am trying that now :) Now the JAR has a lot of `class` files but my code still doesn't work an in fact can't load any class :(

Comment: Maybe update your question. What's the error now? When you run `jar tf` are the dependency classes in the same structure as yours? (e.g. `com/amazonaws/AmazonServiceException.class`)

Comment: Updated question :)

Comment: Can it definitely find the file? In the code it's lowercase: `dynamodb.jar`. In your command, it's `DynamoDb.jar`. I tried to replicate with a gibberish filepath, it gave `ClassNotFoundException` like yours

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry about that. Yeah the file is there and the case is correct.

Comment: What you have should work. But since it's in the same jar, you can take a simpler approach anyway. Try `Class<?> resourceModelClass = Class.forName("com.mparnisa.dynamodb.table.ResourceModel")` and ditch the rest

Comment: That gives `Method threw 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException' exception.` again :(

Comment: For some reason `urlClassLoader.classes` has 0 classes..

Comment: It's not surprising that the list of classes is empty, it will be filled with classes which have been loaded and your attempt to load a class failed. I suggest running the code with a newer JDK, because they will provide a more meaningful message when class loading failed, e.g. naming the failed dependency when a class was present but depends on another class that failed. After identifying the problem, you can turn back to the old Java version.

Comment: Thanks @Holger. Will try that :) I think it's definitely a problem with how I am building the JAR. I am using "IntelliJ artifacts" to build it, but it's definitely not right. Depending on what configuration I use, I get different errors

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFound is also thrown when the class is found but static initialization fails. In this case there should be a more informative exception in the log at program start.