# Generate jar file intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx-8

I want to generate a JAR file of my JAVAFX project in intellij IDEA, but when i do it, when i run the jar, it throw me an exception NullPointerException. The poject has external library jar and i need generate the jar for my final project exam. **It's like the program can't find the main FXML file and can't find the external database file either
**

````
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
        at main.Main.start(Main.java:16)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:187)
        ... 1 more
Exception running application main.Main ```
````

Comment: See https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX.

Comment: i'm using jdk 8

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891.

Comment: still don't work

Comment: There are any packaging standard for javafx applications?