# How do you export a project as an executable .jar in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, executable-jar

It's in the title. I can't figure out how to compile a project (even a small one) as an executable .jar

This is clearly an important first step, so I need to get this figured out as soon as possible. If anybody else uses IntelliJ and knows the step-by-step process, I would be very grateful if you could share it.

Thank you! :)

Comment: IntelliJ can do it natively. File > Project Structure > Artifacts. Don't know any self-respecting developer who uses that feature though. Use Maven.

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/create-jar-from-modules-dialog.html and https://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891 for the sample project.

Comment: Thanks guys, I switched to Eclipse instead, which has a much more intuitive Export process. So, I now have the .jar, but I'm getting a different issue which I'll ask as a separate question