# Java SQL DriverManager unable to locate mariadb driver (IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, mariadb

I have a maven project where I import the mariadb driver directly from a jar file. I'm making a .jar artifact from this project using IntelliJ IDEA. I'm repeatedly getting a `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://ip:3306/db` error. What changes should I make to my project/setup to make `DriverManager` recognize the mariadb driver?

pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.4</version>
</dependency>
```

code (note it's not the connection string - I replaced the info)

```java
package com.bremea.packagename.utils;

import java.sql.*;

public class db {

    private static Connection connection = null;

    public static void init() {
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://ip:3306/db", "uname", "pass");
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you include the driver classes in the jar? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have, the jar file is included in the artifact.

Comment: Did you extract it inside the jar or did you just copy one jar inside the other one? The latter will not work.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I extracted it inside the jar. Screenshot: https://bremea.has.rocks/ktt9ilp3o9a

Comment: Works fine here. Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Easily way to include a JDBC driver in your project.

1. Download connector [here](https://downloads.mariadb.org/connector-java/3.0.0/).
2. Copy the file into your project -> lib folder.
3. Try to compile a code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you reload project? Right click over the file pom.xml and select reload project, maybe the dependency does not was downloaded

Comment: I have refreshed, no effect