# Build Artifact with IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, artifact

I am trying to deploy a JAR into Docker.

The problem I am running into is building the JAR. (with IntelliJ)

I clicked File -> Project Structure then went to 'Artifacts' and clicked the 'Create Archive' button.

I provided a name for the JAR ("SimpleService.jar")

I clicked CREATE MANIFEST and then the following have been done

1. Manifest File location is selected
2. Main class is set to com.oneorangetree.Main
3. Class Path is "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1\lib*.jar"

This is the first time I am trying to deploy a Java application. I am not sure what #2 and #3 should be set to.

[image: Source Code]

[image: Manifest]

Comment: Main class is the class that contains the `public static void main(String[] args)` method that should be executed (you can have multiple classes in a Jar that have a main method).

Comment: so am i supposed to put the File Path in the "Main Class" or the class name like "Main.class"

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891 for the sample working project.

Comment: The demo worked but is there any 'tutorial' that tells you how to do this to your own project?

Comment: You don't need to specify any class path in the manifest. The one you specify explicitly overrides the default classpath and the class is not found.