# SQLException: No suitable driver found when in run my project as a exe JAR file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, derby

I start learning java and this is my first project in java, I tried every StackOverflow answer I could find but it didn't work in my case.

in my project I was required to work whit derbyDB, I run the project in IntelliJ investment and the DB connection work. The problem start when I create a jar file for my project.
When I try to run the jar file I get this exception: 'java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:C\CostManagerDB'

I try with and without:

- Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
- Add java.sql.Driver file to src\META-INF\services, file content: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
- Add modules->dependencies: derby.jar. derbynet.jar, derbyclient.jar, derbytool.jar

My project ended when it try to create a connection, how I can fix that?

My code

```
 import java.sql.*;


 public class CostManagerDB {

// Check if the database exists if not create local database
public CostManagerDB() throws Exception{
    // Check if the database exists
    try {
        Connection conn;
        // Register the DerbyDB JDBC driver
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");

        // Establish a connection to the database
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:C:\\CostManagerDB");
        conn.close();
    }// Create the database if not exists
    catch (SQLException e) {
        // Check if the exception is database not found
        if(e.getSQLState().startsWith("XJ")){
            CreateDB();
        }
        else { throw e; }
    }
}

/* Create a local database for the program whit 2 tables (Expenses, Categories) and add initial data  */
public void CreateDB() throws SQLException{
    // Create the database
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:C:\\CostManagerDB;create=true");

    // Execute a SQL statement to create a new tables
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

    // Create a categories table
    String createCategories = "CREATE TABLE Categories (Id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY " +
            "(START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1), CategoryName VARCHAR(50))";
    stmt.executeUpdate(createCategories);

    // Insert to categories table
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Categories (CategoryName) VALUES (?)");
    pstmt.setString(1, "Grocery");
    pstmt.addBatch();
    pstmt.setString(1, "Books");
    pstmt.addBatch();
    pstmt.setString(1, "Clothing");
    pstmt.addBatch();
    pstmt.setString(1, "Electronics");
    pstmt.addBatch();
    pstmt.setString(1, "Bills");
    pstmt.addBatch();
    pstmt.setString(1, "Entertainment");
    pstmt.addBatch();
    pstmt.executeBatch();

    // Create a expenses table
    String createExpenses = "CREATE TABLE Expenses (Id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY " +
            "(START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),Amount FLOAT, Category VARCHAR(50), Currency VARCHAR(20), " +
            "Description VARCHAR(100),Date DATE)";
    stmt.executeUpdate(createExpenses);

    // Close the statements and connection
    pstmt.close();
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();

}
```

}

Comment: Make sure that Derby JDBC classes were added to the JAR file you're trying to run https://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/12844632

Comment: So, yes, if you don't want to deploy a separate driver jar, the driver must be inside a 'fat jar' along with everything else

Comment: And include the full details of the exception that you get.