# Artifact folder not appearing in 'out' directory in Intellij when trying to make java project executable

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I was trying to make my java project in Intellij executable, I did everything correct step by step, but theres no artifact folder in out after adding artifact, anyone can help? Everything seems to be fine, except out folder. I've been looking for a solution to the problem but nothing helps. I apprecieate any help :)
Here is screenshot what it looks like after all the steps taken and the artifact built:
[Intellij screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZtG0.png)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891 for the sample project.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to go to the main menu, then go to **Build** | **Build Artifacts**

See [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiling-applications.html#build_artifact).