# how to create JAR file in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, jar

I am having a problem on creating a JAR File on Intellij.
What should I do in order to export only pack1 and pack2 to JAR File to directory 'dist'. And I don't want to include directory 'dist' in JAR.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wY5D.png)

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html and https://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891 for the sample project.