# Where is the build artifacts?

Tags: intellij-idea, jar

Trying to follow the [instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html#build_artifact) to package my HelloWorld in a jar.

Where is the Build jar artifacts in the new Community Editions?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it here (under the hamburger menu `≣`):

[image: build artifacts]

You can enable Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance | **Show main menu in a separate toolbar** option to have the main menu always displayed.

Another option is to use Help | **Find Action** and type `Build Artifacts`.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891) for the sample project with the configured artifacts.

Comment: Thank you soo much!  I really appreciate your kindness and time to answer